# Why can't I edit my migrated question?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, migration, user-accounts, serverfault

I have a question [at Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/36826/linux-routing-problem) that was migrated from Stack Overflow. I think the question is not related to my actual user in Server Fault. It's not a reputation problem, but more of a management problem. I can't give it "my own answer" or close it or do anything to it.

Furthermore, I don't know how to answer this question. Meaning, I found the solution: the driver had several bugs, which is okay, that's what I needed to find out. But what do I do? Simply put it in as my answer? Or do close the question?

Comment: If I understand the OP's situation correctly, this is now handled automatically, so the question is obsolete. If I didn't understand correctly, and shouldn't have voted to close, someone please @-notify me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now StackOverflow and MetaOS don't know who your account is on here likely because you hadn't gone through the proper association steps yet. Once you do that you should be listed accurately as the question owner on the post that was migrated.

Comment: How do I do that? When I go to my account at Stack Overflow, it says I have 2 other accounts at SF and meta, and that it can't associate them or something because they were open with Google OpenID.

Comment: Email team@stackoverflow.com. They should be able to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to associate your accounts in your profile [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130404?tab=accounts#sort-top). ServerFault doesn't know who you are.